# Query a thrown exception from a C# App in PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, exception, powershell-3.0

I'm running an app in PowerShell like so:

```
$exe = "C:\blah\build\blah\Release\blahblah.exe"
&$exe scheduledRun sliceBicUp useEditionId
```

`blahblah.exe` is a C# .NET 4.5 Console App. Now I know this executable can throw errors etc. Can I catch these errors/exceptions within the PowerShell script itself?

Basically i want the PowerShell script to detect an error/exception has occurred and action something, like email our Helpdesk for example.

Comment: They run in different processes, so no

Comment: @Liam thanks I thought I would check. I will have to add some handling to log it out and check for a file etc etc within the PowerShell script itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Liam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40090185/query-a-thrown-exception-from-a-c-sharp-app-in-powershell#comment67452976_40090185) mentioned, errors from external programs are not exceptions. If the executable terminates with a proper exit code you could check the [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) `$LastExitCode` and react to its value:

```
& $exe scheduledRun sliceBicUp useEditionId
switch ($LastExitCode) {
  0 { 'success' }
  1 { 'error A' }
  2 { 'error B' }
  default { 'catchall' }
}
```

The only other thing you could do is parse the [output](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/) for error messages:

```
$output = &$exe scheduledRun sliceBicUp useEditionId *>&1
if ($output -like '*some error message*') {
  'error XY occurred'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code. When .Net program exit then error is passed to ps script

```
   $exe = "C:\Users\johnn\OneDrive\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\test\test\bin\Release\test.exe"

   $pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
   $pinfo.FileName = $exe
   $pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
   $pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
   $pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
   $pinfo.Arguments = "localhost"
   $p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
   $p.StartInfo = $pinfo
   $p.Start() | Out-Null
   $p.WaitForExit()
   $stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
   $stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
   Write-Host "stdout: $stdout"
   Write-Host "stderr: $stderr"
   Write-Host "exit code: " + $p.ExitCode
```